# Apache2: How to track client download progress on server side

Tags: apache-2.4, connection

I'm running an Apache2 on Ubuntu Server.
A client downloads a large file (appx. 2GB) from that server using a browser.

How do I track the progress of that download on server-side.
I'd like to see how far a specific download has advanced for the client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible when Apache is serving a static file.

You could however use a script that delivers the corresponding headers and writes the file to the client. That way you can write the current progress to a logfile for example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) from apache?

With

> The status of each worker, the number of requests that worker has performed and the total number of bytes served by the worker (*)

you can come up with a result you seek?

It looks like this:

```
Srv     PID     Acc         M   CPU     SS Req  Conn Child  Slot    Client  VHost           Request
0-22    30807   0/328/6417  _   111.81  2   0   0.0  2.84   37.39   1.2.4.2     
0-22    30807   0/266/5823  _   111.81  2   0   0.0  1.32   32.97   1.2.4.2 conn.local:80   GET /path/to/file HTTP/1.0

Srv     Child Server number - generation
PID     OS process ID
Acc     Number of accesses this connection / this child / this slot
M       Mode of operation
CPU     CPU usage, number of seconds
SS      Seconds since beginning of most recent request
Req     Milliseconds required to process most recent request
Conn    Kilobytes transferred this connection
Child   Megabytes transferred this child
Slot    Total megabytes transferred this slot
```